Copy Data from one column and past at the end of another column
I am trying to find a way to copy all newly added data from column A to a different column. Ideally it would be great if it will only copy new unique data to the new column but if this is not possible, it can copy and past but then id need to add another step to remove duplicates.
Here is an idea of what it needs to do:


You may try:
=QUERY(A2:B, "Select A, SUM(B) Where A is not Null Group by A Label A 'Name', SUM(B) 'Amount'")

OUTPUT

UPDATE
Google Sheet formulas tend to recalculate whenever new data is added in the spreadsheet.
To get the unique names without compromising their location in Column A, you may use:
=UNIQUE(A2:A)

To sum the amounts in Column B, you may use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="", "", SUMIF(A2:B, D2:D, B2:B)))

OUTPUT

Alternatively, you may also use Google Apps Script for this. To make it work, paste the code on the Extensions > Apps Script of the Google Sheet.
This is an example script:
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  if (rg.getColumn() == 1) {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var vl = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var uv = [];
    vl.forEach(row => {
      if (uv.indexOf(row[0]) == -1) {
        uv.push(row[0]);
      }
    });
    sh.getRange(1, 4, uv.length, 1).setValues(uv.map(v => [v]));
  }
}

OUTPUT


Note: The script does not add the sum of Amount since this is only a suggestion. If needed, it can be added as well.

If you'd like to sum the Amount, you may use:
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  if (rg.getColumn() == 1 || 2) {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var vl = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
    var uv = {};
    vl.forEach(row => {
      var nm = row[0];
      var amt = row[1];
      uv[nm] = uv[nm] ? (uv[nm].amt ? { amt: uv[nm].amt + amt } : { amt: amt }) : { amt: amt };
    });
    var op = Object.keys(uv).filter(nm => uv[nm].amt != undefined).map(nm => [nm, uv[nm].amt || ""]);
    sh.getRange(2, 4, op.length, 2).setValues(op);
  }
}

OUTPUT

REFERENCE

QUERY function
UNIQUE function
SUMIF
onEdit(e)


Thank you. That works similar to the filter way I had it but the issue is, if I do any edits or calculations in F2 downwards, and new data gets added, those calculations would be referencing to the wrong name so i was hoping that the "paste" to column D would be actual text and not dynamic.

Gotcha. Let me work on a formula for this.

Hi, @Lalaland. Kindly check if my updated answer would be useful in your situation. If you'd like to use the script for this, I can update my answer, including that information.

Hi there, thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. I will test it soon, just been away from a pc but will check tomorrow.

Thank you so much for the code, it works perfect the only thing it doesn't do is if I remove data from first column, then the data from second column does not get removed. I sent you direct link to my sheet in a chat if you want to check what I mean? Also, can I make this to only work on a certain sheet/book or will this run on any other sheet too?
